Do I have to recompile my project when I change values on property file
This is a general question on Java projects using property files.
Assuming a property file in src/main/resources
enter image description here
in this persistence.properties file you find datasource url and credentials.
If I want to change the datasource from Oracle to Sybase for instance
Do I need to recompile my project for my java app to connect this new database ?
I am expecting to change property values and just relaunch the application without having to recompile.

if you use docker containers, and you put your properties file in a secret, you could indeed just change the properties file, and restart the application

You don't have to recompile your Java source files, because properties are read from the resource files at runtime. But you have to repackage your application. Normally, this is done by either clicking on "Build application" in your IDE, or using the appropriate Maven or Gradle task.
To understand what repacking means, remember that your code does not run from the src directory. Before your application runs, the .java files are compiled to .class files in your build directory, and the resource files are copied to the build directory. The contents of the build directory may then be put into an executable .jar file.
So, when you change a resource file, it needs to be copied into the build directory (and into the .jar file). The safest way to do this is using your IDE or build system (Gradle or Maven).

If I understand well, when doing changes on property file a repackage is mandatory for the changes to be effective on next run ?
What will happen if I change property files inside the .jar ?

That would also work, but you should treat your jar file as a file containing copies of your source. So you can just change the files in your jar, but it's recommended to change them in the source directory too.

Ok, thanks alot for the reply. Unfortunately I am trying to understand how works a very old (and crapy) project from a big corp. So I have very little freedom for providing changes

Loading Runtime Configurations:
You usually don't need to recompile if your program is configured to read the property file dynamically at runtime.
As long as the program can detect or reload changes, many frameworks, including Java's Spring Boot, let modifications to property files without recompilation.
Compilation-Time Property Embedding: You must recompile your project in order for changes to take effect if property file values are embedded within the compiled code (for example, by being turned into constants or included in the build artifacts).
Frameworks for Development Tools:
Changes may take effect automatically without the need for manual recompilation or restarting if you're using a framework or tool with hot-reloading capabilities, like webpack in a JavaScript project or devtools in a Spring Boot application.

Hello, thanks for the reply
How do I know if I am using Runtime or Compilation-Time properties ?
Actually trying to debug an extra old project (written in early 2010s)
